# cannot convert parameter 5 from 'SIZE_T *' to 'size_t *' -- why?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I'm getting this error when compiling for 32-bit.  The same file compiles with no errors for 64-bit Windows

> 1>c:\project\test.cpp(1317) : error C2664: 'StringCbCopyExW' : cannot convert parameter 5 from 'SIZE_T *' to 'size_t *'

Both SIZE_T and size_t have the same size and sign so what is the difference?  Why do I need a cast here?  And if the types are different, why is this an error only on 32-bit Windows?

Comment: Could You do sizeof for size_t and SIZE_T on 32-bit Windows?

Answer (score 6):

`SIZE_T` is different from `std::size_t`. The first is a type `#define`d in the windows headers, the second is a type defined by your C++ compiler. They are different types.

At least on my system, `SIZE_T` is a `typedef` for `ULONG_PTR`, which is a `#define` for `unsigned long`.

Comment: For 64-bits it is `typedef unsigned __int64 ULONG_PTR, *PULONG_PTR;` for 32-bits it is `typedef _W64 unsigned long ULONG_PTR, *PULONG_PTR;`.   In either case these should be aliases for the same integer type.

Answer (score 0):

what is SIZE_T defined as?

It might be defined as "unsigned int", or uint32_t for backward comaptibility

Comment: `typedef ULONG_PTR SIZE_T, *PSIZE_T;`