# cannot convert parameter from 'SIZE_T *' to 'size_t *' - how to cast?

Tags: c++, winapi, casting, size-t

On some Windows API call, I get: `cannot convert argument 6 from 'size_t *' to 'SIZE_T *'`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5215243/552510) tells me that `SIZE_T` and `std::size_t` are different types. I know that both describe the same thing, just by different SDKs (C compiler vs. Windows SDK), so I want to cast

```
reinterpret_cast<SIZE_T *>(&my_size_t_var)`
```

Is there a less-ugly way to do it?

**Edit:** `SIZE_T` is (when compiling for 64-bit targets, at least):

```
typedef ULONG_PTR SIZE_T, *PSIZE_T; 
typedef unsigned __int64 ULONG_PTR, *PULONG_PTR;
```

**Edit2:** I'm using Win32 compressions API, specifically [`Compress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh437548(v=vs.85).aspx), which has a parameter `_In_  SIZE_T UncompressedDataSize`, which I want to call with some `std::vector<byte>.size()`.

Comment: Yes, C++ is case-sensitive, so `SIZE_T` is at least as a symbol not the same as `size_t`. What the right solution is depends really on what your `SIZE_T` is defined as. Show us what `SIZE_T` is.

Comment: "How to cast?" is the wrong question, use the correct types instead.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: I take it you have never had to program in an environment that uses one type, and have to pass it to something else that requires a different type. Yes, it would be possible to do `size_t temp = my_SIZE_T_var; ... my_SIZE_T_var = temp;`, but I think that's just as unportable and more work than using a cast.

Comment: Picking the correct type is the first thing to do, converting should always be considered a workaround. Up to now, I haven't seen any indication that this can't be performed without any conversion. Also, @Mats, rest assured that I have worked in such mixed environments, between standard C++ and win32 API even, so I know what I'm talking about.

Comment: This question could be improved by giving a concrete example of where you're forced into using mismatching types.  Where are you getting the `std::size_t` and what API are you trying to call?  Do you actually need pointers or are you just getting tangled up trying to convert a `std::size_t` to a `SIZE_T`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:

```
static_assert(sizeof(size_t) == sizeof(SIZE_T), "Expect size_t to be same size as SIZE_T");
```

somewhere near your `reinterpret_cast<SIZE_T*>(&my_size_t_var)`.

This will ensure that they are compatible in size, which is the key point.

Comment: The types cannot be automatically converted due to different signed-ness, not different sizes. `size_t` and `SIZE_T` are the same size on Windows; the `static_assert` - while not wrong - doesn't really buy you anything either.

Comment: It does show that they are not different size - and one may assume that a `size_t` isn't validly going to be a negative value (I hope!)

Comment: Seems to me that if `size_t` and `SIZE_T` are different sizes, something is *very* wrong with your build environment.  (But OK, it doesn't hurt to be paranoid.)

Answer (score 0):

They are the same types on x86-64, but on x86(32 bits) they are not. `SIZE_T` is `unsigned long` and `size_t` is `unsigned int` on x86 so you have to use either `reinterpret_cast` or C-style cast: `(SIZE_T*)&my_size_t_var`.
Alternatively you can switch to x86-64. I'm afraid these are the only options you have in this case.

Comment: There's no such thing as "x86-32".

Comment: There's the option of doing it right and not casting at all.

Comment: @ixSci: If you've invented it then you should define it, or stick to already-accepted terminology.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, what if the author has different parts of his program, one is Windows specific and the other is not? He has to use SIZE_T because of the API and it is proper to use size_t on the crossplatform part. So you can't use one type everywhere.

Comment: @ixSci: You're naming an architecture that doesn't exist. It is impossible to unambiguously interpret what you've written.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, well since it seems so "important", I've changed it.

Comment: I'm aware that such glue code may be impossible to write cleanly, @ixSci. However, writing it cleanly should be the goal and not applying casts to shut up the compiler.